# Time of cooking: induction stove vs gas stove

Tags: cooking-time, stove, electric-stoves, induction

If I get a 2000W, portable, table-top, induction burner (one hob), how would cooking time change as compared to a gas stove (pre-heat time and overall time that would take to cook something)? On a gas stove my pan heats up for several seconds. What about at 3000W?